# Quoting a quote of a person who was interrupted in a scholarly book

Tags: technical-writing, quotes

> ROBERT Thank you. Ladies and gentlemen, let me tell you a story. It
> begins with a garden, a cherished place of solace for my family...
>
> ROBERT ...and that's when I discovered the irreparable damage.
>
> DANIEL (Interrupting) Your Honor, I must object. These allegations are
> baseless and exaggerated.
>
> ROBERT (Cut off by DANIEL) Your Honor, may I continue?
>
> ROBERT I have photographic evidence, irrefutable proof of the damage.
>
> ROBERT In conclusion, I implore this court to grant me the
> compensation I seek for the endured damages.

This is a court transcript. Not realistic, but I wanted something short. I want to remove the interruption by Daniel in my scholarly book. How do I do this, and how do I format it?

> "Thank you. Ladies and gentlemen, let me tell you a story. It begins
> with a garden, a cherished place of solace for my family... and that's
> when I discovered the irreparable damage. **Your Honor, may I continue?**
> I have photographic evidence, irrefutable proof of the damage. In
> conclusion, I implore this court to grant me the compensation I seek
> for the endured damages."

I am not sure if I should mention the part in bold, and I don't know how I mention that he was interrupted. Is there something I need to add to show he was interrupted before the bolded part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Quotes that are longer than 40 word (APA) or longer than four lines of text (MLA) should be quoted as blockquotes.
2. Quotes must preserve the markup of the original (including capitalisation).
3. Quotes must be verbatim or paraphrases. Verbatim quotes are in quotation marks, paraphrases of direct speech are in subjunctive.
4. Ellipses must be signalled by three full stops ("...")

---

Your quotation gives the false impression that the source contained exactly those words in exactly that formatting and markup and that the person you cite said exactly that in front of the court, all of which is untrue.

A proper scholarly quotation would look exactly like the original, word for word, except for a different font being used.

Comment: Why was the question downvoted?

Comment: @Sayaman I didn't downvote.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't imply you did it, but I was wondering if there was something wrong with it, because I thought it was a perfectly fine question.